# Crypto | TypeError: X509Certificate is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const { X509Certificate } = require('crypto');

function getCertificateThumbprint(certificate)
{  
  const cert = new X509Certificate(Buffer.from(certificate, 'base64'));
  return cert.fingerprint;
}
```

I practically copied this code from the crypto documentation code, also this is most likely not a problem with package installations, because crypto is built-in node.js module. Same error, when passing a plain string and not a Buffer.

Comment: Could you debug to check the contents of X509Certificate? If you can't debug, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(X509Certificate)); Let's see why it's not a constructor.`

Comment: I tried reproducing myself, and crypto doesn't include X509Certificate so that may be the problem we both have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `X509Certificate` class was added recently in NodeJS version v15.6.0. Ensure you are using v15.6.0 or newer so that your import works.

Comment: Yes, this was the case, i just got confused because other exports from crypto were working fine.